# Hero transitions inside container view

Tags: ios

I am showing viewControllerA in a container, and want to present modally the viewControllerB over it (modal in container, not fullscreen). To achieve it I am calling:

```
viewControllerB.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
viewControllerA.definesPresentationContext = true
viewControllerA.present(viewControllerB, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Dismissing it also goes without problems:

```
viewControllerB.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The views behave normally until the moment I want to enable hero transitions. I've added heroIDs to 1 textfield on each of the VC's. IDs are correct, because the same VCs on iPhone (viewControllerA not in a container, viewControllerB presented modally fullScreen) are transitioning correctly. After the dismissal viewControllerA's frame is going outside of the screen. Sometimes the ViewControllerA's textSearchButton is also hidden (UI inspector shows it's in its place, though).

Do you have any suggestions where to look for the cause of the error?

EDIT:
To enable hero I call:

```
viewControllerA.navigationController?.hero.isEnabled = true
viewControllerA.hero.isEnabled = true
viewControllerB.navigationController?.hero.isEnabled = true
viewControllerB.hero.isEnabled = true

viewControllerA.contentView.textSearchButton.hero.id = HeroViewId.propertyAddressTextField.rawValue
viewControllerB.contentView.searchTextField.hero.id = HeroViewId.propertyAddressTextField.rawValue
```

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://github.com/HeroTransitions/Hero), it looks like for it in order to work you have to:
1. `controller.hero.isEnabled = true`
2. `view.hero.id = "something"` on the matching pairs
3. add some modifiers to the views you want to animate.

Can you add to the question the code in which you do these at least three things?

Comment: @SimoneChelo Updated with setup of heroIDs